# Primefaces Tree SelectListener resets other form inputs

Tags: jsf, tree, primefaces

I've got a problem with the SelectListener of the primeface component tree.

Update: What I want to do is creating a group and chosing a path from a tree. So I have the group name, and the tree for the path. After selecting a path, underneath the tree the selected path should be shown and updated by an AJAX request.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<h:form id="groupCreate">

   <p:inputText id="createGroupName" value="#{groupContainer.name}" />

   <p:tree id="pathTree" update="groupCreate" selectionMode="single"
         selection="#{groupContainer.selectedPath}" dynamic="false"
         value="#{groupContainer.rootNode}" var="node" cache="false"
         nodeSelectListener="#{groupContainer.onNodeSelect}">
      <p:treeNode>
          <h:outputText value="#{node[1]}" title="#{node[0]}" />
      </p:treeNode>
   </p:tree>

   <!-- Display selected Path from tree -->
   <h:outputText value="#{groupContainer.chosenPathString}/>

   <p:commandLink id="createButton" .../>

</h:form>
```

The onNodeSelect function in my bean looks like this:

```
public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {  
    //get the selected data and set it
    this.chosenPathString = //selected Text;
}
```

This generally works - means after the AJAX request the chosen path is shown. However if I input some text int the `createGroupName` input field, and afterwards select a node, after the AJAX request the `createGroupName` is set to null again.

So my AJAX request for updating the selected path name of the tree **resets all my current typed values**. After some debugging i found out that the AJAX request ignores all my typed values, because they are not commited yet (like they would be, if i submit the form). But how can I change my code to get this to work?

Any help would be appreciated, and sorry for my bad english in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `p:tree` updates the whole form. This means that the form is re-rendered. In order to save other form input values you either need to submit the whole form `onNodeSelect` or update only the form elements that really need to be updated.

Assign an id to the `h:outputText` for the selected path and change your `update` attribute of `p:tree`, such as:

```
<h:form id="groupCreate">

   <p:inputText id="createGroupName" value="#{groupContainer.name}" />

   <p:tree id="pathTree" update="choosenPath" selectionMode="single"
         selection="#{groupContainer.selectedPath}" dynamic="false"
         value="#{groupContainer.rootNode}" var="node" cache="false"
         nodeSelectListener="#{groupContainer.onNodeSelect}">
      <p:treeNode>
          <h:outputText value="#{node[1]}" title="#{node[0]}" />
      </p:treeNode>
   </p:tree>

   <!-- Display selected Path from tree -->
   <h:outputText id="choosenPath" value="#{groupContainer.chosenPathString}/>

   <p:commandLink id="createButton" .../>

</h:form>
```

Comment: Oh my god, you don't know how many hours I worked on this problem. Now it works. In my actual form I'm using many more elements so I thought before I write all the element ID's I just provide the form ID to spare some time for typing.
Thank you very very much!